# How can a graphic be placed in the OneUI .lotusBanner area using the Application Layout Control

Tags: xpages

I am using the Extension Libraries Application Layout Control and need to have a banner graphic placed in the .lotusBanner div on the right. How can this be done as it seems that the Application Layout Control can't be modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to place a graphic in the upper right of the Application Layout Control in the Banner area by doing the following:

1. In the control under the Banner > Utility links I added a Basic node. For the node I specified the href and image. This worked and placed the image n the correct spot.
2. Artifacts of this were the location of the Banner Application links. To remedy this I used some CSS for the .lotusBanner ul.lotusLinks {margin-top: 45px;position:absolute;}
3. The margin-top was to push the links down so I could enlarge the logo that is used by the Application Layout Control.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the utilityLinksFacet on the extended control that Steve Pridemore did.

http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=CED2E61A75526CD086257997006DA95B

or you could use onload javascript to add it.

Answer (score 1):

The applicationLayout control in ExtLib is, as you have found out, locked down to only allow certain aspects of the configuration to be changed by the developer. You can add links to different sections of the applicationLayout but nothing beyond that.

One possible alternative is to NOT use the applictionLayout control itself but create your own approximation of it in a custom control, You would need to add all the necessary panels/divs with the special oneUI2 classes in all the correct places and then add editable areas and callbacks within these panels for the parts that you would want to customize throughout the application. All of the other sections in the applicationLayout control, like the bannerUtilityLinks are created using the ListofLinks control that is also found in the Extension Library.

Comment: I've done the manual route before (re: http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/oneuidoc/docpublic/index.htm ). It isn't fun. :) Or maybe the layout control has made me lazy.

Comment: I've done the manual route myself and I agree it isn't fun. However if done correctly you can implement it as a single custom control with facets areas just like the applicationLayout control and make development just that little bit faster.

Comment: Trying a few things out. I was able to get an image to appear using the utility links. Now I am trying to get the links on the left to be lower. Getting there. Thanks for the suggestions.